# How do I iterate across a list of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an hash like this:

```
@json = [{"id"=> 1, "username" => "Example"}, {"id"=> 2, "username" => "Example 2"}]
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <% @json.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.username %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

and it would output a list with the two usernames.

Just tried this in IRB:

```
json2 = [{"id"=> 1, "username" => "Example"}, {"id"=> 2, "username" => "Example 2"}]
irb(main):076:0> json2.each do |user|
irb(main):077:1* user["id"]
irb(main):078:1> end
=> [{"id"=>1, "username"=>"Example"}, {"id"=>2, "username"=>"Example 2"}]
irb(main):079:0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html), not a `User` object. Therefore, you must access the username using the index operator (`[]`):

```
<ul>

<% @json.each do |user| %>
  <li><%= user["username"] %></li>
<% end %>

</ul>
```

Comment: @Railsbeginner, what you are seeing is the return value of the `each` method, which is the `json2` array. Try calling `map` instead.

Comment: @Railsbeginner, it depends. Read the documentation and learn what the [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method does. if you understand how it works, you will be able to make good decisions. With that said, using [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) as I have used on my answer should work fine on the partial.

Comment: `map` would be the wrong thing to use inside an ERB file. `map` is good when you want to iterate through the elements of an array and coerce the values into something else. You shouldn't do that in a view; Views are for displaying values ready for insertion into a page and `each` fits into that.

Comment: Is it possible to parse the JSON to create an activerecord obj?

Comment: @Railsbeginner, that is outside the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

```
json2 = [{"id"=> 1, "username" => "Example"}, {"id"=> 2, "username" => "Example 2"}]
json2.each do |user|
    puts user['username']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need output in console, then you need to do as follows:

```
@json = [{"id"=> 1, "username" => "Example"}, {"id"=> 2, "username" => "Example 2"}]
@json.collect{|json| puts json['username'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate hash which is in array you can use any of this.

```
@json = [{"id"=> 1, "username" => "user_name"}, {"id"=> 2, "username" => "user_name"}, {"id"=> 3, "username" => "user_name"}]

@json.each{|json| puts json['username'] } 

@json.collect{|json| json['username'] } 

@json.map{|json| json['username'] }
```

If you want in the view then you can use

```
<ul>
  <% @json.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user["username"] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```